# Got the filter function working but dont know how to apply it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Good day,

as a newbie in React i am trying to make an ecommerce website. And one of the features i want to include is the abilty to search up the specific products. I have made the filter function and the searchbar component, but i dont know how to apply it. Since i have used Redux also, without 100% understanding it.

the product Component where i wan to apply the filter:

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import {Library} from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import {faShoppingBasket} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import { listProduct, Filterproducts } from '../../actions/productActions'





function Product(props){
    //default value is an array, because we've got data in an array 
    const [qty,setQty] = useState(1)
    const productList = useSelector(state=>state.productList)
    const{products,loading,error}=productList
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    

    
    

    useEffect(()=> {
        dispatch(listProduct())
        
       


  

    }, [])

    // handlefilter

    // handle cart adding
    const handleAddToCart = ()=> {
        props.history.push('/cart/' + props.match.params.id +  "?qty" +qty)
    }

 

  


   
    return( 
        // Check the loading before rendering products
        loading? <div><h1 className="load">loading...</h1></div> : 
        error?<div>{error}</div>:
           <ul className="products">
               
            {products.map(product=> (
            
                
        
            <li key={product.id} className="product"> 
             <Link to={"/product/" + product.id}><div className="img" style={{background: `url(${product.img})`, backgroundSize: 'cover'}}></div></Link>
                   {/* LOOK OUT FOR TYPOS IN ROUTIING  dont put':' after /, this only applies
                   when routing because the ": " implies for a parameter
                   In this case you can directly access product.id  */}
               <Link to={"/product/" +  product.id}><h1>{product.name}</h1></Link> 
                <p> <small>€</small>{product.price}</p>
                <div>size: {product.size}</div>
              
                {product.qty > 0 ? <div><button onClick={handleAddToCart}>Add to cart</button>  <div>{product.qty} left</div></div> : <div>out of stock</div> }   
               
             
                
                </li> 
                )
                
                )}
   
                 </ul>
                
                 
       
    
    )
}
export default Product
```

The store template where i have got the filter function:

```
import React,{Component, useState} from 'react'
import Product from '../components/product'
import Nav from '../components/nav'
import Footer from '../components/footer'
import Searchbar from '../components/searchbar'
import Filter from '../components/filter'


class Store extends Component{
   
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            products: [],
            SearchProduct: ''
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/')
        .then(res=> res.json())
        .then(data=>this.setState({products:data}) )
       
    }
   
   render(){
       let filteredProducts = this.state.products.filter((product)=> {
            return product.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.SearchProduct.toLowerCase())
       })
    return (
        
        <div>
        <Nav/>
        <div className="store">

           
            <div className="title">
                <h1>Store</h1>
            </div>
            <aside>
                <Searchbar 
                placeholder="Search" 
                handleInput={(e)=> {
                   
                    this.setState({SearchProduct: e.target.value})
                }
                 
                } 
                />
                
                <ul>
                    <h2>Categories</h2>
                    <li>Women</li>
                    <li>Men</li>
                    <li>Clothing</li>
                    <li>Equipment</li>
                 
                </ul>
            </aside>
           
           <Filter/>
            
            <Product filter={filteredProducts}/>
            
         
           
        </div>
        <Footer/>
        </div>
    )
   }
   
}

export default Store
```

The searchbar component:

```
import React from 'react'


// Function Searchbar 
//Looks for products 

function Search(props){

   
    return(
     <input 
     type="search"
     className="search"
     placeholder={props.placeholder}
     onChange={props.handleInput}/>
    )
}

export default Search
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the exact question is. Maybe this tutorial on [react filtering](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/react-filter-filtering-arrays-in-react-with-examples) will help you.

Comment: @DylanLandry the question is: how do i apply my filterproducts to my products component.

Comment: @Reactord I think you just need to use `prop.filter` in your Product component to get the results of filteredProducts.

Comment: @AntonijaŠimić where exactly in the component?

Comment: @Reactord Why not filter in the [selector](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors), that's what they are usually used for: `const productList = useSelector(state=>state.productList.filter(....))`

Comment: @HMR ×
TypeError: state.productList.filter is not a function